# Magento remove product from category programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I have found the following piece of code to remove a product from a category:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
```

However I'm not sure how to use it!  The product I wish to remove has id `13409` and the category id is `7`

How do I get the above to work? I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->7,$p‌​roduct->13409);
```

Comment: can i get complete working code?

Comment: My code not working : https://justpaste.it/1eh7x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To programatically remove a product from category, try this :

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct('7','13409');
```

You just need to pass the `category_id` and the `product_id` not the collection

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.  I'm so dumb haha!